# Cannot read kABPersonPhoneProperty

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, abaddressbook

I'm facing a (strange) problem: I'd like to retrieve the number of phone's numbers of a contact but, for some reason, I am not able to.

I used

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
NSArray *contacts = (NSArray*) ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
CFRelease(addressBook);
```

to get the array of all the contacts. Then I would like to use

```
ABMultiValueRef ref = ABRecordCopyValue([contacts objectAtIndex:i], kABPersonPhoneProperty);

NSLog(@"%d",ref==NULL);
```

but `ABRecordCopyValue` always returns `nil`...
Notice that I'm able to retrieve other informations about the contact: for example, extracting the name works fine using

```
CFStringRef name = ABRecordCopyCompositeName([contacts objectAtIndex:i]);
```

May someone explain me what I'm doing wrong? I'm using Snow Leopard with Xcode 4.2 and I'm developing for iOS 4.0...

EDIT: I found a solution: instead of using

```
ABRecordCopyValue([contacts objectAtIndex:i], kABPersonPhoneProperty);
```

I used

```
ABRecordID idRec = ABRecordGetRecordID([contacts objectAtIndex:i]);
ABMultiValueRef ref = ABRecordCopyValue(ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, idRec), kABPersonPhoneProperty);
```

However I had to keep valid the reference to `addressBook` (do not release it), thus the solution suggested by EricS seems better.

Comment: It should work. Try a different multivalue such as `kABPersonEmailProperty`. Could it be that everyone you've tested on has no phone numbers? Also, apropos of nothing, I'd suggest writing `NULL == ref`; the other way round, accidentally leaving out an equal sign will raise no error and get misleading results. :)

Comment: Nothing changed. In my address book there are only two test contacts: the first has two numbers and one email, while the second has 1 phone number and no email. In both cases it returns nil...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is just a guess, but I would try keeping the address book open until you're done reading from it. That is, don't call `CFRelease(addressBook);` until after reading all the phone numbers.

The address book is more like a database than a flat file and reading in a contact record gives you references to other fields & data rather than all of the actual field content.

Comment: I found another solution, but conceptually is the same as your, but your is easier (check the edit in my question). :) However I don't understand very well why my original approach should not work...the documentation seems a little bit superficial about...