# How to get email address and name from iPhone address

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have tried this but it crashes:

```
- (NSDictionary *)contacts {

    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

    CFRelease(addressBook);

    NSArray *peopleArray = (NSArray *)people;

    //  Return if there are no contacts in the address book
    if (peopleArray && peopleArray.count > 0) {

        for (int i = 0; i <= peopleArray.count - 1; i++) {

            ABRecordRef person = [peopleArray objectAtIndex:i];
            ABRecordID sourceID = ABRecordGetRecordID(person);

            ABMutableMultiValueRef multiEmail = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);

            NSString *emailAddress = (NSString *) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiEmail, 0); //EXE BAD ACCESS

            [emailAddress release];
            CFRelease(multiEmail);

            NSLog(@"email address %@", emailAddress);

            NSString *sourceId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", sourceID];

            NSLog(@"%@", sourceId);
        }
    }

    if (peopleArray) CFRelease(people);
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:result];
}
```

Comment: Where does it crash? What's the error message?

Comment: Try the following: 1) Build and Analyze; fix any warnings you get 2) enable zombies 3) see if `multiEmail` is set to a legitimate value, and if not, work backwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to release `addressBook` until you have done. I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630738/cannot-read-kabpersonphoneproperty) and that fixed the issue.